# Cakephp 3 - Name convention in plurals

Tags: cakephp, model, naming-conventions, cakephp-3.2

Maybe this is a simple question but I didn't find it in cookbook.
I am confused when name for some plural words with 'ies"

Example:
City -> Cities

- Controller: CitiesController
- Table: CitiesTable
- **Model: City ???? or Citie ???**

Now both made error when I run the app. Error did't find model name.

Thank you for any answers and sorry if my English is too bad.

---

UPDATE June 28th 2016
I found the solution. In fact, I just kept their name:

- Controller: **CitiesController** in src/Controller/CitiesController.php
- Table: **CitiesTable** in src/Model/Table/CitiesTable.php
- Model or Entity: **City** in src/Model/Entity/City.php

It works for me.

Thank for all.

Comment: **Model**? Did you maybe mean **Entity**? Whenever receiving errors, please always post the _complete_ error message including the _full_ stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!

Comment: Some googling reveals it: [singular](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/inflector?string=city) vs [plural](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/inflector?string=cities). But the docs in general state that quite cleary. Especally since in 3.x and table classes both controller and table (model) are plural. Only the entity is not.

Answer (score 1):

General use of the controller/entity/table name is the singular form of the noun(in your case `CityController`, `CityTable` and `City`). This removes the confusions between the singular and plural.

Another good practice is that your tables in the DB to be named with the singular of the entity they represent (for example your table is `city` , therefore your Table class should be called 'CityTable') . So you can always relate the information in the source with the tables in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Update Aug 11th 2016

Hi all,

Sorry for long time to answer this. I was quite busy. I found out my answer. I didn't use the "city" table only. I used "m_cities" instead. (M means Master). So all my files and classes name are:

Model > Entity:

```
MCity.php
```

Class:

```
class MCity extends Entity{
... 
}
```

Model > Table

```
MCitiesTable.php
```

Class:

```
class MCitiesTable extends Table
{
...  
}
```

In the class MCity in file MCity.php. I defined the initialize with following content for declare the table name for CakePHP understand my table name.

```
parent::initialize();
//Define used table name in database
$this->table('m_cities');
```

So final content of this class is:

```
class MCity extends Entity
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize();
        //Define used table name in database
        $this->table('m_cities');

    }//end initialize

}//end class
```

All are worked OK for my project until now. Because of somebody didn't see my update in post so I re-update as answer for searching people.

Thank you all.